# C++ template - compile member function based on arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, type-traits

Suppose that a class has a member function which should accept either a double(double) function or a class instance with a "MyStructFunc" public member function as an argument:

```
#include<functional>
#include <type_traits>
struct Caller
{
    // (1.)
    double call(std::function<double(double)> func) { return func(1); }

    // (2.)
    template<typename T>
    double call(const T& S) { return S.MyStructFunc(2); }
};
```

So, for example, we can pass

```
double myFunc(double x) { return x * x * x; }
```

or

```
struct myStruct
{
    double MyStructFunc(double x) const { return x * x; }
};
```

like this:

```
int main()
{
    Caller c;
    myStruct ms;
    c.call(myFunc);
    c.call(ms);
}
```

Unfortunately, I get an error. Could you please help me make it work? Thank you for your help!

Comment: What error(s) do you get, and on which line(s)?  [Edit] your question to include these details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

function pointer is not a `std::function`, so your template method is a better match.

You might use SFINAE to restrict your template method:

```
// (2.)
    template<typename T>
    auto call(const T& S) -> decltype(S.MyStructFunc(2)) { return S.MyStructFunc(2); }
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea18783f6c4800be)